# Clearing ComboBox in VB - WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I have a combobox that needs to be refreshed when the user selects a new item in my ListView.  The problem I've run into is the

```
comboboxProblems.Items.Clear()
```

It throws an error:

```
"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"
```

The refresh works fine as long as the user does not change the selection in comboboxProblems before selecting a new ListView item.  However if the comboboxProblems selection changes and then a new ListView item is selected then it will throw the error.

I've tried a few different things, but none have worked.  An example of something I've tried is:

```
If comboboxProblems.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            comboboxProblems.Items.RemoveAt(comboboxProblems.SelectedIndex)
            comboboxProblems.SelectedIndex = -1
            comboboxProblems.Items.Clear()
```

I've tried all I can think of any ideas?

Also this is how the combobox is populated if that matters.

```
   Try
        problems = problem.GetAll()
        comboboxProblems.Items.Clear()
        For Each problem In problems
            Dim i As ComboBoxItem = New ComboBoxItem
            i.Content = problem.Description
            i.Tag = problem.ProblemID
            comboboxProblems.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorRoutine(ex, "LoadProblems")
    End Try
```

Comment: seems like a weird exception for Clear to throw. Is this code being called in an eventhandler?

Comment: Could you not use XAML to Bind the ItemSource to a property of the SelectedItem of the ListBox